# MATLAB struct - Multidimensional data structure if only one dimension is well defined at the start?

Tags: matlab, data-structures, struct, programmatically-created

**Goal:** I have 5 folders of `.wav` files. I created a vector of directory paths, and then I want to load all the `.wav` file data and do the same type of analysis on all the components. However, I need to be able to differentiate between sound types, so each folder's `.wav` file data needs to have it's own column or row.

```
%% defined all the paths <--- later link these to buttons


    Words=[Ball, Daddy,Jeep, No, Tea_Pot]; 
%%each variable corresponds to the path for the sound directory
```

Earlier, I wrote functional code to process each sound individually, by asking the user to choose the directory.

```
dname=uigetdir('C:'); %this should be linked to a button
cd(dname); %make current directory, the directory specified by the path
files=dir('*.wav'); %get all the .wav files in the folder
for k=1:length(files);
    audio=cell(1, length(files));
    audio{k} = audioread(files(k).name);
end
wavfilenum=length(files);
% files <-- wavefile x 1 struct array with fields:
% name, folder, date, bytes, isdir( is a directory/folder), datenum (serial
% date number)
```

The problem is that I know the length of Words, because I know the number of folders I have, but I don't know how many files I have.

How do I make a data-structure, to hold 
[image]

for all the words?

Comment: Use a cell array. Each directory is a cell, within each cell you keep the struct array returned by `dir`.

Comment: Or a two-level struct: `data.Ball = dir(Ball);`